# How to create a flexible adaptive table-like layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-tables

Don't know if this question is simple or no, but I got stuck with it: is it possible to create a flexible adaptive table-like layout which changes it's columns amount depending on a window width?

Illustration:
[image: A visual example of the layout i talk about] 
(***green*** border means **initial** size of a block (size of a block contents), **black** border means **calculated/rendered** size of a block)

The goal is to create a layout in which:

1. Blocks are aligned like in a table - has the same space between them,
2. The height of a row is the height of the block with the greatest height in this row,
3. Columns amount are changing depending on a window width, for example there will be 1 column if the width is less than 300px, 2 column - 500px, 3 columns - 750px and 4 columns - >1000px

Actually, I already achieved this with JS and its not very hard for my PC to execute the script I wrote, so I think the script is optimized well, but anyway I hope that it can be done with pure CSS.

I can show my solution (CSS+JS), but I think it has no value.

Comment: This is basic flexbox with media queries.

Comment: Can you please show me an example of this basic flexbox? I have no experience using flexbox because of its support, so i'd really appreciate if you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox and media queries can do this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  background: #c0ffee;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .box {
    flex: 0 0 48%;
    background: #bada55;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
  .box {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
    background: rebeccapurple;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box {
    flex: 0 0 24%;
    background: #b19d09;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, totam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, cum. Voluptate natus quaerat eaque incidunt, accusamus veniam facere, alias provident odio est rerum commodi?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, dolore.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>lorem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nobis odit possimus porro. Nihil, modi.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium vel, accusamus cupiditate esse quisquam, nisi hic dolores assumenda adipisci, illum ab itaque nemo placeat! Dolorum aliquam iure veritatis reprehenderit libero.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LkqyGw?editors=1100#0)

[**A Complete Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) @ CSS-Tricks.com

Comment: Thanks! Are there some other ways of doing this using CSS, without flex?

Comment: flex box is the way to go! see both https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://flexbox.help/ for more info.